# Non-negative integral solutions to a single equation

Tags: diophantine-equations

Assume we have a integral vector $c\in \mathbb{Z}^n$ and an integer constant $b\in \mathbb{Z}$. Is there a necessary and sufficient condition for whether or not there exists a non-negative integer vector $x\in \mathbb{Z}^n_+$ such that $c^Tx=b$?

If so, if there is not such vector $x$, is there then a way to find a maximal $b' < b, b'\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that there exist such an $x$?

My motivation comes from a desire to strengthen constraints for MILP's.

Comment: Look up the Frobenius problem.

Comment: @J.M. I assume you are referring to the coin problem? Doesn't that assume that the vector $c$ is non-negative?